# Size of Set Equal to 1? $|U \cap \{s,t\}| = 1$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I am not sure what to call this but in the preliminaries for chapter 2 on sets in Alexander Schrijver's Combinatorial Optimization book he states the following:

A set $U$ is said to separate $s$ and $t$ if $s \neq t$ and $|U \cap \{s,t\}| = 1$

The part I am confused about is what operation would result in $|U \cap \{s,t\}| = 1$. I would understand if it was $\emptyset$ or $\{s,t\}$ or a subset of $\{s,t\}$, but I don't understand how it would equate to $1$.

Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: $|A|$ is the *cardinality* of the set $A$, i.e. the number of its elements. Thus $|A|=1$ means that set $A$ ans **only one** element.

Comment: The vertical bars mean "number of elements", so there's exactly one of $s$ or $t$ in the intersection.

Comment: This says simply that $U$ contains just one of $s$ or $t$, not both. So it "separates" that one from the rest of the underlying set.

Comment: More specifically, $|U \cap \{ s,t \} |=1$ means that the *intersection* of sets $U$ and $\{ s,t \}$ has **only one** element, i.e. that either $s \in U$ or $t \in U$, but **not** both.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! makes perfect sense now

Comment: The condition could also be written as $s\in U\leftrightarrow t\notin U$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\cdot|$ means cardinality, so the condition is that exactly one of $s,t$ is an element of $U$